# Number elements starting from the middle element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an odd number of elements.

```
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

I wonder how to give them a numbered class in jQuery, count from the middle element, like this:

```
<div class="line no2"></div>
<div class="line no1"></div>
<div class="line no0"></div>
<div class="line no1"></div>
<div class="line no2"></div>
```

anyone?

Edit:

Before, I will check the amount of elements. If the amount is an even value I'm adding an additive element to have an odd number of elements.

I want to archieve a circle text shape, [like this example (see curve)](http://www.csstextwrap.com/examples.php). The number of lines is not really important, because the middle line `<div class="line no0"></div>` will be the vertical center of the circle.

Comment: What if the count of the elements be an even number?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? We're not here to do it for you, we're here to help you understand how to do it yourself.

Comment: I agree with @BlackSheep and also, are you going to handle just 5 elements?

Comment: I will check the amount before, if the value is an even number, i add an additional element. So the number is always an odd value.

Comment: Have you attacked the problem in a specific way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
var middle=Math.ceil($("div").length/2);
var divs=$("div.line");
divs.each(function (){
    $(this).addClass('no'+Math.abs(middle-(divs.index($(this))+1)));
});
```

http://jsbin.com/IKiGexIr/5/edit

Shorter version : ( PSL )

```
var middle=Math.ceil($("div").length/2),divs=$("div.line");
    divs.addClass(function (i){ return 'no'+ Math.abs(middle-(i+1)); });
```

[image]

Comment: Nice... Or bit more shorter `divs.addClass(function (i){
    return 'no'+ Math.abs(middle-(i+1));
});`

Comment: @PSL yes I know(regarding the var), I just wanted to make it clearer rather than shorter. regarding the `i`  - you're right Ill edit

Comment: oh well that is clearer as well.. :)

Comment: you dont need each. Instead you just need addClass, since it internally does an loop anyways.. But got to give it to you, `Math.abs` never occurred to me when i posted... :) Here http://jsbin.com/IKiGexIr/8/edit

Comment: @PSL abs was the last part I had to struggle.  the first and main struggle was to find the formula to yield the appropriate figures.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
var h = parseInt($('.line').length / 2, 10);
$('.line').each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass('no' + (i < h ? h - i : i - h))
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/PE7Js/)

Comment: Excellent aproach...nice

Comment: +1 first to answer and works, nice.

Comment: thanks. and works faster than accepted http://jsperf.com/math-vs-no-math

Comment: +1 for code performance

Answer (score 3):

Just try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var indice = 0;
$("div").each(function(){
  indice++;
});
var mid = (indice / 2 ).toFixed();
var aux = 1;
var start = mid - 1;
$("div").each(function(){
    if(start > -1)
    {
        $(this).addClass("no"+start);
        start --;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("no"+aux);
        aux ++;
    }   

});

});
```

Working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/7pnUP/1/